# Epsilon proofs (for algebra of limits, etc.) clarification

Tags: real-analysis

So in some epsilon proofs I've seen, such as the proof that the sum of the limits  [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitProofs.aspx) they use

$N$ = min{$N_1, N_2$}

or $N$ = max{$N_1, N_2$}

I understand that you would choose the maximum of $N_1,N_2$ since it provides the smaller neighbourhood for $\epsilon$, but why was min{$N_1,N_2$} sometimes chosen? If $n>N_1$ couldn't $n \not > N_2$, or vice versa?

Another thing is why is it sometimes written:
Given $\epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \mid n\geq N$

But also sometimes written $n > N$?

When do we use each instance, or does it not matter?

Comment: There is no difference in writing $>$ or $\geq$ in those statements since, if there exists $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies something, then there exists $N'=N-1$ such that $n>N'$ implies the same thing, and viceversa.

Comment: In my experience $min\{N_1,N_2\}$ is used when $N_1$ and $N_2$ limit the size of an interval $|x-c|<N_1$ for example in a $\epsilon-\delta$ proof of limits as given in your link. However, maximums are used in reference to the convergence of sequences of numbers where you cant choose a interval but how far out in the sequence you can go where the sequence allegedly converges to some fixed point.